# Import MySQL Database : No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Im am trying to get the following script to import a database. Every time I run the script I get a

```
mysql -u username -pmypassword my_database < /var/hostdata/databases/my_database.sql
-bash: /var/hostdata/databases/my_database.sql: No such file or directory.
```

At one point this script would work for me but now it isn't. Also everything I am reading online say this should work but obviously its not. What am I doing wrong? I am running MySQL 5.5.41 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What does `ls -l /var/hostdata/databases/my_database.sql` say?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `/var/hostdata/databases/my_database.sql` is MIA as error states

`No such file or directory.`

make sure file actually exists on file system by issuing:

`ls -1  /var/hostdata/databases/my_database.sql`

`mysql` import command is correct, you just need to make sure you're importing an actual mysql dump.

Comment: I am an idiot. I ran the ls -l and it did not find the file. So I went into the directory and noticed that instead of using an underscore I had a dash. I apologize. I worked on this for about an hour or 2 the other day.

Comment: @thebradnet don't beat yourself up, feel free to accept my answer)